# javascript function always return true even validation is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have this js function, but it always return true (even when the validation is successful and doesn't matter i set the 2 values tu false:

what am I missing ?

```
function ValidaCajadeTextoVacia(clicked, controlID) {
  //para sacar los datos porque estan en una masterpage
  var dynCtrl = clicked.id.substring(0, clicked.id.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
  var tBox = document.getElementById(dynCtrl + controlID);

  var CajaSinEspacios = jQuery.trim(tBox.value);
  //alert(CajaSinEspacios);
  //return false;
  if (CajaSinEspacios.length == 0) {
    alert('en blanco');
    return false;
  }
  else {
    alert('lleno');
    return false; //true
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that calls this function?

Comment: eh, i don't believe you. that simply isn't possible. are you sure you don't have the function defined twice, with the second one still having true in the else? are you getting either of the alerts? how are you coming to the conclusion that it's returning true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i found my mistake

i had the function WITHOUT RETURN ON HTML

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnGuardar" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/imagenes/boton.guardar.jpg"  OnClientClick="ValidaCajadeTextoVacia(this,'txt_rol');MensajeCargandoJQUERY();"      />
```

and the correct form is

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnGuardar" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/imagenes/boton.guardar.jpg"  OnClientClick="return ValidaCajadeTextoVacia(this,'txt_rol');MensajeCargandoJQUERY();"      />
```

Comment: i was just testing, this is the new code:

`function ValidaCajadeTextoVacia(clicked, controlID) {
    //para sacar los datos porque estan en una masterpage
    var validar = false;
    var dynCtrl = clicked.id.substring(0, clicked.id.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
    var tBox = document.getElementById(dynCtrl + controlID);

    var CajaSinEspacios = jQuery.trim(tBox.value);
    //alert(CajaSinEspacios);
    //return false;
    if (CajaSinEspacios.length == 0) {
        //alert('en blanco');
    }
    else {
        //alert('lleno');
        validar = true;
    }
    return validar;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling it like following:

```
onclick="return ValidaCajadeTextoVacia()"
```

OR for asp.net button:

```
onClientClick="return ValidaCajadeTextoVacia()"
```